# Value of a scaled Bessel function for negative argument

Tags: special-functions

Is the function $\hat{i}_0(x) = e^{-|x|} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}} I_{\frac{1}{2}}(x)$ positive or negative for negative $x$?

$I_{\alpha}(x)$ above is a [modified Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions_:_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1).

Here are my arguments. Considering that $I_{\frac{1}{2}}(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}} \sinh(x)$, $\hat{i}_0(x)$ can be represented as follows:

$$ \hat{i}_0(x) = e^{-|x|} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}} \sinh(x)$$

$$ \hat{i}_0(x) = \frac{e^{-|x|} \sinh(x)}{(\sqrt{x})^2}$$

Using [the convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Square_roots_of_negative_and_complex_numbers) that $\sqrt{x} = i\sqrt{-x}$ for negative $x$, we get

$$ \hat{i}_0(x) = \frac{e^{-|x|} \sinh(x)}{x}$$

which is positive for negative $x$:

[image: plot of \hat{i}_0(x)]

However, using the original formula, [Wolfram Alpha says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%28-%7Cx%7C%29%20sqrt%28pi/%282x%29%29%20BesselI%5B1/2,%20x%5D) that the function is negative for negative $x$:

[image: plot of \hat{i}_0(x)]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Ignoring the scaling for the moment (it's always positive, so we can ignore it for now), you have the [modified spherical Bessel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedSphericalBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) $\mathrm{i}_0(x)=\frac{\sinh\,x}{x}$, which is always nonnegative...

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks for the pointer. Any ideas why Wolfram Alpha thinks differently?

Comment: I gave an explanation in the comment to Robert's answer; note that *Mathematica* is the thing that's running behind Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: You could give the following function to Wolfram Alpha, though: `Exp[-Abs[x]] SphericalBesselJ[0, I x]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're missing is that $\sqrt{1/x}$ is not the same as $1/\sqrt{x}$ when $x$ is negative.
Indeed, $\sqrt{1/(-1)} = \sqrt{-1} = i$ but $1/\sqrt{-1} = 1/i = -i$.  You might try asking Wolfram Alpha for $e^{-|x|} \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2x}} I_{1/2}(x)$.

Comment: *Mathematica*, being the careful sort, evaluates the OP's function (omitting the scaling factor) as `(Sqrt[1/x] Sinh[x])/Sqrt[x]`; since the `Sqrt[1/x]/Sqrt[x]` is always positive, `Sinh[x]` is the only way the function can be negative and indeed it does become negative for negative argument.

Comment: @Robert Israel: You are right. Thank you for pointing this out.